# how to get a python value from input type hidden in jquery

Tags: jquery, python, web2py

I have this code:

```
<div class="popup" data-popup="popup-1">
    <div class="popup-inner">
        {{=form.custom.begin}}
            <div style="display:none">
                <input id="co_srid" type="hidden" value='{{=form.custom.widget.service_request_id}}' />
        {{=form.custom.end}}
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var cosrid = $("#co_srid").val();
    alert("value is-" + cosrid);
});
```

I want to get the value of `#co_srid` that has a value from a Python code, now I when I `alert` the value I get this

[image]

Is there anyway I can get the value `9` only?

Comment: Your `{{=form.custom.widget.service_request_id}}` code is outputting an entire HTML string. You should find a way to output *only* the `9` value you need. Then your code will work as it is

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank you for that information, i will try that.

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
value='{{=form.custom.widget.service_request_id}}'
```

to

```
value='{{=get_data.service_request_id}}'
```